# How to represent less than half seconds using Kotlin's kotlin.time library?

Tags: kotlin

I am working on a Kotlin project where I need to represent durations in a millisecond. I am using the `kotlin.time` library, and I'm a bit confused about the correct syntax for expressing durations less than half seconds.

For example, I want to represent less than half seconds. I tried using the following code:

```
val halfSecond = 500.milliseconds
```

Is it correct?

Comment: TLDR: yes. What do you think it is not?

Comment: You first mentioned "fractions of a millisecond" in title, then "less than half seconds", then "half a millisecond", then named your variable "halfSeconds", then assigned it a value of "0.5 milliseconds". I am confused. Do you want 0.5s or 0.0005s?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the question.

Comment: Your question is still confusing. You're still using variable name `halfSeconds` but setting it to half a millisecond. In fact `500.milliseconds` is half a second.

Comment: And as you asked for "correct syntax for expressing durations less than half seconds" - an example is `499.milliseconds`.

Comment: @k314159 what is correct description for? can you please guide me? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's either `val halfSecond = 500.milliseconds` or `val halfMillisecond = 0.5.milliseconds`. What you currently have is `val halfSeconds = 0.5.milliseconds` which is a misleading variable name for a value that doesn't represent what the name implies.

Comment: Thank you @k314159, I fixed the variable name. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: `0.5.milliseconds` is not half a second. It's one two-thousandth of a second.

Comment: so 500. milliseconds is half second right?

Comment: Yes, 500 milliseconds is exactly half a second.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, see [kotlin milliseconds doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/milliseconds.html).
In `0.5.millisonconds`, 0.5 is a double type value, then kotlin calls the `Double.milliseconds` extension to return a duration.

> `inline val Double.milliseconds`
> Returns a Duration equal to this Double number of milliseconds.

So, in terms of the number type, there are three forms to get a duration object.

```kotlin
val time1 = 10.milliseconds // for int
val time2 = 10L.milliseconds // for long
val time3 = 10.0.milliseconds // for double
```